# Finding some maps $T \in L(V,V)$ with some properties

Tags: vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Assume that $V$ is a vector space and $T \in L(V,V)$ is a linear transformation.

Questions:

1. Provide a golden structure on $\mathbb R^2$. ( We say $T \in L(V,V)$ is a golden structure if we have $T^2-T+I_v=0$)
2. Find a nearly complex structure on $\mathbb R^2$. ( We say $T \in L(V,V)$ is a nearly complex structure if we have $T^2=-I_V$ )
3. Show that there is no nearly complex structure on $\mathbb R^3$.

Note: My problem is that i don't have a method for finding such linear transformations.

Comment: For #2, think about rotations...

Comment: @TylerGaona thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't go into more detail about what you are confused about, I am only providing two hints, not a complete answer.

For $V = \mathbb{R}^2$, any $T\in L(V,V)$ can be represented as a 2 by 2 matrix. Thus the equations $T^2 - T + I =0$ and $T^2 = -I$ reduce to 4 equations involving four variables -- try to find simple solutions.

For the no nearly complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^3$, it might be helpful to note the following generalization: a nearly complex structure exists on $\mathbb{R}^n$ if and only if $n$ is even -- it actually is no more difficult to prove for arbitrary $n$ (at least the non-existence for $n$ odd).

Comment: 4 equations involving 4 variables... i don't get it... would u please explain it more?

Comment: Write explicitly $T = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d  \end{bmatrix}$. Then you will get a matrix equation, on the LHS the entries of the matrix will be polynomials of $a, b,c,d$ on the RHS the entries will be $-1, 0, 0, -1$. (I.e. $T^2 - T = - I$ and $T^2 = - I$.) Then choose as many of $a,b,c,d$ to be $0$ or $1$ or some other simple number as possible. It's kind of laborious to write out in LaTeX, which is why I hesitated to say more.

Comment: Thank you... and how do we know that "..." iff $n$ is even?

Comment: Only one direction is really relevant for 3: complex structure does not exist if $n$ is not even (i.e. odd). Assume a complex structure existed, and derive a contradiction using the fact that the determinant of $-I$ is $-1$ for $n$ odd and $1$ for $n$ even.